# Opencart 1.5.4: Remove Hidden Products from Featured Module

Tags: opencart

I'm using the multistore feature but when I use the featured products module, I only want certain categories in my sub-domain. At the moment, the products I'm not displaying in the sub are showing as an empty space. How can I get rid of them and just show the assigned products? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In file

> file catalog/controller/module/featured.php

pls replace

```
$this->data['products'][]
```

to

```
if(!empty($product_info['status'])) $this->data['products'][]
```